# Хто такий дитинолог?

Tags: значення-слів, етимологія

На сайту "Добробут" зустріла цікаве назву статті  "[20 найкомічніших моментів на прийомі у дитинолога](https://www.dobrobut.com/ua/news/c-20-samyh-komicnyh-momentov-na-prieme-u-ditinologa)".

Хто такий ***"дитинолог"***? Логічно припустити, що це лікар з дитячих хвороб. Проте ні СУМ-11, ні СУМ-20 даного слова не знає.

В СУМ-11 присутнє визначення більш вживане та відоме

> [ПЕДІА́ТР](http://sum.in.ua/s/pediatr) Лікар, спеціаліст з дитячих хвороб.

Чи нормативно використовувати дане слово в діловому письмі? Де взялося дане слово?

Comment: "Але в клініці Добробут, де саме і винайшли цей новий термін..." https://medprosvita.com.ua/v-ukrayini-z-yavilisya-likari-ditinologi/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ви праві, лікар-дитинолог - це те саме, що педіатр чи дитячний лікар згідно до інформації на [цьому сайті](https://medprosvita.com.ua/v-ukrayini-z-yavilisya-likari-ditinologi/) ("Згідно визначенню Антимонопольного комітету України, «поняття педіатрія та дитинологія є тотожними»"). Термін цей був винайдений у лікарні "Добробут" та використовується для рекламування послуг їхніх педіатрів.

Comment: посилання в вашому пості може згнисти, тому варто процитувати джерело